# What is the meaning of these letters above the soprano part in Monteverdi's SV 332?

Tags: chords, notation, renaissance-music

Consider following score of Monteverdi's *Sì dolce è 'l tormento* for soprano and continuo (SV 332) from [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/S%C3%AC_dolce_%C3%A8%27l_tormento%2C_SV_332_(Monteverdi%2C_Claudio)). What is the meaning of the capital letters above the soprano part? They do not seem to correspond to chord names.

[image]

Comment: @PiedPiper  maybe?  and "E" over a pair of D notes seems odd, as does a "D" over an A and E note pair.

Comment: @ PiedPiper: it can't be this. a) what chords? b) later in the sheet there are O and other letters.

Comment: Any chance they indicate organ stops?  I don't know what organ music indicators look like

Comment: Very interesting. I couldn’t find any source about this notation.

Answer (score 5):

The letters correspond to particular tablature of the 5-sting guitar popular at the time. Here's one tablature translation from: 
http://www.patriciadixon.net/guitar-lit-html/italianbaroque.htm

[image: qu]

Comment: Now that you've identified the answer perhaps you should delete all of the earlier speculation or at least relegate it to a footnote.  Also, if the letters are editorial, they are the work of a 17th century editor, as you can see by looking at the first link in the IMSLP page.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the 5-string guitar would have been tuned E-B-G-D-A like the top five strings of the modern guitar, and the diagram is inverted compared to modern tablature notation.